# Svg is not showing in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, svg, icons, storybook

tried multiple solutions, but it goes nowhere.

Svg icons are not displayed in storybook, but works everywhere except this case.
There're multiple warnings related to icons in storybook
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqP6G.png)
Icons are exported in index.ts file like
`export { ReactComponent as expand } from './expand.svg';`

webpack.config.js

```
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

const moveRuleToFront = (config, loaderPattern) => {
  const { rule, index } = config.module.rules
    .map((rule, index) => ({ rule, index }))
    .find(
      ({ rule }) =>
        rule.use &&
        rule.use.some((entry) => entry.loader.includes(loaderPattern))
    );
  config.module.rules.splice(index, 1);
  config.module.rules.unshift(rule);
};

module.exports = (config) => {
  moveRuleToFront(config, '@svgr');

  return {
    ...config,
    output: {
      ...config?.output,
      publicPath: '',
    },
    devServer: {
      ...config?.devServer,
      hot: true,
      static: {
        ...config?.devServer?.static,
        directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        publicPath: '/public',
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      ...(config?.plugins || []),
      new ESLintPlugin({ extensions: ['js', 'ts', 'jsx', 'tsx'] }),
      new CompressionPlugin(),
    ],
  };
};
```

webpack.config.js for storybook tried with and without Nx plugins

```
const { composePlugins, withNx, withWeb } = require('@nrwl/webpack');

// Nx plugins for webpack.
module.exports = composePlugins(withNx(), withWeb(), (config) => {
  const imageRule = config.module.rules.find(rule => rule.test.test('.svg'))
    imageRule.exclude = /\.svg$/

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack']
    })

  return config;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Note

My solution was addressing the same issue with react and storybook, but I was also using rollup.js. I hope this solution helps you anyway.

## Background

I had a similar issue as OP describes. The code below was fully working on react, but when I had to show the component on Storybook it didnt work.

```
// Close.svg
<svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M12 4L4 12" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
<path d="M12 12L4 4" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>
```

```
// in some component
import { ReactComponent as CloseIcon } from '../assets/icons/Close.svg';
```

## My solution for Storybook 7 for component built with rollup.js

I had to change it like this (it could also be because I am using rollup.js):

```
// CloseIcon.tsx
import * as React from 'react';

function SvgClose() {
  return (
    <svg
      width="16"
      height="16"
      viewBox="0 0 16 16"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        d="M12 4L4 12"
        stroke="currentColor"
        strokeLinecap="round"
        strokeLinejoin="round"
      />
      <path
        d="M12 12L4 4"
        stroke="currentColor"
        strokeLinecap="round"
        strokeLinejoin="round"
      />
    </svg>
  );
}

export default SvgClose;
```

```
// import in some component
import CloseIcon from '../../../assets/icons/CloseIcon';
```

I have seen other people suggest another solution: re-exporting the icon but that did not work for me (maybe it works for you since you dont have rollup):

```
// CloseIcon.tsx
export { ReactComponent as CloseIcon } from './Close.svg';
```

## Conclusion

I agree that this is not the most elegant approach, but it seems to be working for me.